# How can i auto get form's data for perl6?

Tags: raku, bailador

a form like this:

```
<form action='1.php' method='post'>
u:<input name='u' type='text'/><br />
p:<input name='p' type='password'/><br />
<input value='submit' type='submit'/>
</form>
```

and how can i auto get the form data use perl6?
lkie this:

```
my $form = xxx($the_form_url)
```

and the result like this:

```
$form.Str
#output like that:
#u=username&p=password&submit=submit
```

have shome modules in perl6?
please..

Comment: Are you looking for a [`WWW::Mechanize`](https://metacpan.org/pod/WWW::Mechanize) like module in Perl 6?

Comment: I'm not up to date on P6 webdev, but at the time of writing this the #1 place to browse P6 modules that folk have shared is [modules.perl6.org (mpo)](http://modules.perl6.org/). (CPAN / metaCPAN support is work in progress.) A [search of mpo for 'params'](http://modules.perl6.org/#q=params) lists [HTTP::ParseParams](https://github.com/retupmoca/P6-HTTP-ParseParams). It looks like you'd need to use it with something that handles requests. I see modules matching 'http', 'request', 'cgi', 'web'. I know szabgab et al are currently fleshing out [Bailador](https://github.com/Bailador/Bailador).

Answer (score 1):

Bailador is indeed a good tip.

But if you want a more CGI-line approach, have a look at SCGI;
https://github.com/supernovus/SCGI